# datefns format is not completely formatted

Tags: javascript, date-format, date-fns

I am using react and datefns.

I have the following code

```
import { enUS, ja } from 'date-fns/locale';
import { format, isValid, parseISO } from 'date-fns';


export const getDateLocal = (locale?: string) => {
  switch (locale) {
    case 'ja':
      return ja;
    case 'en':
    default:
      return enUS;
  }
};

export const localizedDateFormatter = (
  date: Date | number | string,
  dateFormat = 'MMM dd',
  locale = 'en'
): string => {
  const dateIsIso = typeof date === 'string' ? isValid(parseISO(date)) : false;
  if (!date || (!dateIsIso && !isValid(date))) {
    return '-';
  }

  return format(new Date(date), dateFormat, { locale: getDateLocal(locale) });
};
```

I call this function like this

`localizedDateFormatter(hoverFrom, 'MMM dd, yyyy', i18n.language) // can be ja or en`

The problem is, the date is not converted like I would like.

```
ja: 12月 15, 2020 

en: Dec 15, 2020
```

While it should be

```
ja: 2020年1月13日 (or at least 1月13日, 2020年)

en: Dec 15, 2020
```

Why so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### DISCLAIMER

I have not clue about japanese, so I can give an answer just looking at the source code, but maybe some japanese speaker could give a more precise answer.

---

You can check the locale source code here https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/tree/master/src/locale/ja/_lib, but here are some insights I managed to discover.

**DAY**

The `日` character follows the day on its **ordinal** form (also it seems to be the name for Sunday). Look at [here](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/blob/master/src/locale/ja/_lib/localize/index.js#L136). So you need `do` (ordinal day of month).

**MONTH**

The `月` character follows the month number when displaying the month's name (abbreviated or full). So if you use `M` to display the month it won't show. You need `MMM` or `MMMM`. Compare [JA](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/blob/master/src/locale/ja/_lib/localize/index.js#L15) with [EN-US](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/blob/master/src/locale/en-US/_lib/localize/index.js#L19).

**YEAR**

The `年` character follows the year only if the date is in long format. This character is nowhere in [this](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/blob/master/src/locale/ja/_lib/localize/index.js) file, but it is [here](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/blob/master/src/locale/ja/_lib/formatLong/index.js#L3) on the long and full date format (`PPP` and `PPPP`).

---

The japanese format that you are looking for is `PPP` which shows dates like this:

- **EN**: February 15th, 2020
- **JA**: 2020年2月15日

The closest you can get to the format you where looking for is `MMM do, yyyy`:

- **EN**: Feb 15th, 2020
- **JA**: 2月 15日, 2020

Comment: that's some really interesting stuff, will check at those more in details, thanks

Comment: yeah, looks like that is the only way, I don't like having to put full date, but will do some postformat. thank you